# VxWorks with Eclipse - missing header files

Tags: c++, c, cmake, eclipse-cdt, vxworks

I want to compile a library for **VxWorks 6.8** using **Cmake** and **Eclipse 3.7 Indigo CDT** (with VxWorks *Pentium* and *Power-PC* compilers set). The cmake steps work fine and I get ready-to-use Eclipse project.
But compiling fails because of missing headers.

**Example:**

```
#if defined __VXWORKS__
#include <sys/socket.h>
// some more includes here
#endif
```

This fails because `sys/socket.h` is missing.
Include directory `C:/<path to vxworks>/target/h` where most headers are available (including `sys` directory, but there’s *no* `socket.h` in it!) is set.
The missing `socket.h` is `C:/<path to vxworks>/target/h/wrn/coreip/sys`. Both paths are set as include directories – nevertheless  is still missing.

I’ve started writing some *“dummy headers”* – headers which are placed in the proper subdirectory of `target/h` and only include the actual headers from`target/h/wrn/coreip`. This solution works, but these headers include some more headers on their own, so those need such a workaround too (and then the new one needs some more …).
I’m wondering why it doesn’t work even with include paths set in eclipse.

Most headers of VxWorks don’t have this issue; it seems only those for Network.

Is there any *magic trick* or something I’m missing?

---

*Missing header Error Message:*

> error: sys/socket.h: No such file or directory

A *Warning* i get while compiling:

> [vxworks path here]/h/vsbConfig.h:42:2: warning: #warning
>   "VxWorks Source Build (VSB) project not specified; using default
>   VxWorks UP configuration under $WIND_BASE/target/lib/h/config"

Environmentvariables `WIND_BASE`, `WIND_HOME` and `WIND_LIC_PROXY` are set in eclipse.

I'm crosscompiling from Win7.

Comment: would you mind sharing your cmake Cross-Compilation files?
I am struggling with getting vxWorks6.9 cross-compilation working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding the path to include directories in eclipse is not enough. you have to add it to *cmakelists* too. You can use `include_directories("[your path here]")` to do so.

Comment: Thanks, now all headers are available.